# Add labels (count) to bar plot ggplot for large dataset in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, ggplotly

So I have a barplot of cars and numbers tested and I'm trying to add the counts of each car on it's bar but the numbers are just clustered at the foot of the bar, below is my code

```
cars %>%
  mutate(Brand = fct_reorder(Brand,Total-test,.fun = sum)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Brand, y=Total)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="blue",width=0.4) +
  coord_flip()+
  geom_text(aes(label=Total-test), hjust=-10)
```

[image]

[image]

```
dput(head(cars,50))
```

`structure(list(vehicle = c("ALFA ROMEO-147-2003", "ALFA ROMEO-147-2004",  "ALFA ROMEO-147-2005", "ALFA ROMEO-147-2006", "ALFA ROMEO-147-2007",  "ALFA ROMEO-147-2008", "ALFA ROMEO-147-2010", "ALFA ROMEO-155-1997",  "ALFA ROMEO-156-1999", "ALFA ROMEO-156-2000", "ALFA ROMEO-156-2001",  "ALFA ROMEO-156-2002", "ALFA ROMEO-156-2003", "ALFA ROMEO-156-2004",  "ALFA ROMEO-156-2005", "ALFA ROMEO-159-2006", "ALFA ROMEO-159-2007",  "ALFA ROMEO-159-2008", "ALFA ROMEO-159-2009", "ALFA ROMEO-159-2010",  "ALFA ROMEO-159-2011", "ALFA ROMEO-166-2004", "ALFA ROMEO-BRERA-2006",  "ALFA ROMEO-BRERA-2007", "ALFA ROMEO-BRERA-2008", "ALFA ROMEO-GIULIA-2017",  "ALFA ROMEO-GIULIETTA-2010", "ALFA ROMEO-GIULIETTA-2011", "ALFA ROMEO-GIULIETTA-2012",  "ALFA ROMEO-GIULIETTA-2013", "ALFA ROMEO-GIULIETTA-2014", "ALFA ROMEO-GIULIETTA-2015",  "ALFA ROMEO-GIULIETTA-2016", "ALFA ROMEO-GIULIETTA-2017", "ALFA ROMEO-GT-2005",  "ALFA ROMEO-GT-2006", "ALFA ROMEO-GT-2007", "ALFA ROMEO-GT-2008",  "ALFA ROMEO-GT-2009", "ALFA ROMEO-GT-2010", "ALFA ROMEO-MITO-2009",  "ALFA ROMEO-MITO-2010", "ALFA ROMEO-MITO-2011", "ALFA ROMEO-MITO-2017",  "ALFA ROMEO-OTHER-1996", "ALFA ROMEO-OTHER-2001", "ALFA ROMEO-OTHER-2002",  "ALFA ROMEO-OTHER-2003", "ALFA ROMEO-OTHER-2009", "ALFA ROMEO-OTHER-2010" ),` Vehicle Make`= c("ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO",  "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO",  "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO",  "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO",  "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO",  "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO",  "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO",  "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO",  "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO",  "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO",  "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO"),`Vehicle Model`= c("147", "147",  "147", "147", "147", "147", "147", "155", "156", "156", "156",  "156", "156", "156", "156", "159", "159", "159", "159", "159",  "159", "166", "BRERA", "BRERA", "BRERA", "GIULIA", "GIULIETTA",  "GIULIETTA", "GIULIETTA", "GIULIETTA", "GIULIETTA", "GIULIETTA",  "GIULIETTA", "GIULIETTA", "GT", "GT", "GT", "GT", "GT", "GT",  "MITO", "MITO", "MITO", "MITO", "OTHER", "OTHER", "OTHER", "OTHER",  "OTHER", "OTHER"),`Year Of Birth`= c(2003, 2004, 2005, 2006,  2007, 2008, 2010, 1997, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005,  2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2004, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2017,  2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2005, 2006, 2007,  2008, 2009, 2010, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2017, 1996, 2001, 2002, 2003,  2009, 2010), Total = c(9, 12, 19, 24, 43, 46, 13, 7, 9, 7, 22,  8, 37, 42, 21, 40, 123, 164, 83, 56, 27, 6, 9, 14, 10, 94, 17,  92, 15, 10, 13, 25, 8, 25, 35, 40, 45, 51, 12, 10, 43, 26, 33,  7, 6, 16, 10, 7, 32, 45), PASS = c(2, 3, 6, 8, 10, 23, 4, 3,  4, 0, 5, 1, 12, 12, 6, 17, 42, 56, 30, 20, 13, 0, 3, 3, 6, 56,  10, 58, 8, 9, 11, 22, 5, 23, 13, 11, 16, 16, 3, 3, 26, 14, 17,  5, 4, 7, 5, 2, 18, 16),`PASS % `= c(22.2, 25, 31.6, 33.3, 23.3,  50, 30.8, 42.9, 44.4, 0, 22.7, 12.5, 32.4, 28.6, 28.6, 42.5,  34.1, 34.1, 36.1, 35.7, 48.1, 0, 33.3, 21.4, 60, 59.6, 58.8,  63, 53.3, 90, 84.6, 88, 62.5, 92, 37.1, 27.5, 35.6, 31.4, 25,  30, 60.5, 53.8, 51.5, 71.4, 66.7, 43.8, 50, 28.6, 56.3, 35.6),`

please note the count(Total) scale is up to 200,000

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you use ggplot to make a bar chart, you can set the name with a negative number in the vjust. In case you put this argument after the "coord_flip", you need to change this argument to hjust. Here is an example with the reproducible data I was able to make in these minutes:

```
library("dplyr")
library("ggplot2")
library("forcats")
data(mtcars)

cars <- as.data.frame(cbind(mtcars,rownames(mtcars)))
names(cars)[names(cars) == 'rownames(mtcars)'] <- 'Brand'

cars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Brand, y=wt)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="blue",width=0.4) +
  coord_flip()+
  geom_text(aes(label=Brand), hjust=-0.2)
```

Which gives you the following output:

[image]

For next time I suggest uploading the complete code that leads to the graphic you are currently producing. I don't have your "count" label, but a negative hjust should work.

---

After comments i did this:

```
library("dplyr")
library("ggplot2")
library("forcats")
data(mtcars)

vehicle = c("ALFA ROMEO-147-2003", "ALFA ROMEO-147-2004",  "ALFA ROMEO-147-2005", "ALFA ROMEO-147-2006", "ALFA ROMEO-147-2007",  "ALFA ROMEO-147-2008", "ALFA ROMEO-147-2010", "ALFA ROMEO-155-1997",  "ALFA ROMEO-156-1999", "ALFA ROMEO-156-2000", "ALFA ROMEO-156-2001",  "ALFA ROMEO-156-2002", "ALFA ROMEO-156-2003", "ALFA ROMEO-156-2004",  "ALFA ROMEO-156-2005", "ALFA ROMEO-159-2006", "ALFA ROMEO-159-2007",  "ALFA ROMEO-159-2008", "ALFA ROMEO-159-2009", "ALFA ROMEO-159-2010",  "ALFA ROMEO-159-2011", "ALFA ROMEO-166-2004", "ALFA ROMEO-BRERA-2006",  "ALFA ROMEO-BRERA-2007", "ALFA ROMEO-BRERA-2008", "ALFA ROMEO-GIULIA-2017",  "ALFA ROMEO-GIULIETTA-2010", "ALFA ROMEO-GIULIETTA-2011", "ALFA ROMEO-GIULIETTA-2012",  "ALFA ROMEO-GIULIETTA-2013", "ALFA ROMEO-GIULIETTA-2014", "ALFA ROMEO-GIULIETTA-2015",  "ALFA ROMEO-GIULIETTA-2016", "ALFA ROMEO-GIULIETTA-2017", "ALFA ROMEO-GT-2005",  "ALFA ROMEO-GT-2006", "ALFA ROMEO-GT-2007", "ALFA ROMEO-GT-2008",  "ALFA ROMEO-GT-2009", "ALFA ROMEO-GT-2010", "ALFA ROMEO-MITO-2009",  "ALFA ROMEO-MITO-2010", "ALFA ROMEO-MITO-2011", "ALFA ROMEO-MITO-2017",  "ALFA ROMEO-OTHER-1996", "ALFA ROMEO-OTHER-2001", "ALFA ROMEO-OTHER-2002",  "ALFA ROMEO-OTHER-2003", "ALFA ROMEO-OTHER-2009", "ALFA ROMEO-OTHER-2010" )
Vehicle_Make = c("ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO",  "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO",  "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO",  "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "BMW", "ALFA ROMEO",  "Audi", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO",  "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "Audi", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO",  "ALFA ROMEO", "BMW", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO",  "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO",  "ALFA ROMEO", "Audi", "BMW", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO",  "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO",  "ALFA ROMEO", "ALFA ROMEO")
Vehicle_Model = c("147", "147",  "147", "147", "147", "147", "147", "155", "156", "156", "156",  "156", "156", "156", "156", "159", "159", "159", "159", "159",  "159", "166", "BRERA", "BRERA", "BRERA", "GIULIA", "GIULIETTA",  "GIULIETTA", "GIULIETTA", "GIULIETTA", "GIULIETTA", "GIULIETTA",  "GIULIETTA", "GIULIETTA", "GT", "GT", "GT", "GT", "GT", "GT",  "MITO", "MITO", "MITO", "MITO", "OTHER", "OTHER", "OTHER", "OTHER",  "OTHER", "OTHER")
Year_Of_Birth= c(2003, 2004, 2005, 2006,  2007, 2008, 2010, 1997, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005,  2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2004, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2017,  2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2005, 2006, 2007,  2008, 2009, 2010, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2017, 1996, 2001, 2002, 2003,  2009, 2010)
Total = c(9, 12, 19, 24, 43, 46, 13, 7, 9, 7, 22,  8, 37, 42, 21, 40, 123, 164, 83, 56, 27, 6, 9, 14, 10, 94, 17,  92, 15, 10, 13, 25, 8, 25, 35, 40, 45, 51, 12, 10, 43, 26, 33,  7, 6, 16, 10, 7, 32, 45)
PASS = c(2, 3, 6, 8, 10, 23, 4, 3,  4, 0, 5, 1, 12, 12, 6, 17, 42, 56, 30, 20, 13, 0, 3, 3, 6, 56,  10, 58, 8, 9, 11, 22, 5, 23, 13, 11, 16, 16, 3, 3, 26, 14, 17,  5, 4, 7, 5, 2, 18, 16)
PASS_percentage = c(22.2, 25, 31.6, 33.3, 23.3,  50, 30.8, 42.9, 44.4, 0, 22.7, 12.5, 32.4, 28.6, 28.6, 42.5,  34.1, 34.1, 36.1, 35.7, 48.1, 0, 33.3, 21.4, 60, 59.6, 58.8,  63, 53.3, 90, 84.6, 88, 62.5, 92, 37.1, 27.5, 35.6, 31.4, 25,  30, 60.5, 53.8, 51.5, 71.4, 66.7, 43.8, 50, 28.6, 56.3, 35.6)

cars <- as.data.frame(cbind(Vehicle_Make, Total)) %>% mutate(Total=as.double(Total))

cars <- cars %>% 
  group_by(Vehicle_Make) %>% 
  summarise(Total = sum(Total))

cars %>% mutate(Brand = fct_reorder(Vehicle_Make,Total,.fun = sum)) %>% ggplot(aes(x=Brand, y=Total)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="blue",width=0.4) +
  coord_flip()+
  geom_text(aes(label=Total), hjust=-0.1)
```

Confirming your problem was more about repeated values than the hjust (which, btw, should be between -1 and 0, not -10). Obtaining this, you should be able to replicate:

[image]

Notice I added some Brands at hand in the data, not a concerning issue Because you have the data with many of them. Hope it solves your issue!

Comment: thanks for contributing! instead of using coord_flip, it's shorter and probably safer to just switch x and y aesthetic - here `aes(x = wt, y = Brand)`

Comment: thanks @ignacio2424 I'm having multiple counts on one bar, I'll Edit the question and post a screenshot of what I'm getting. the dataset is large, hence why i can put it here.

Comment: To better handle your question, could you do something like dput(head(cars, 50)) and post it here?

Comment: Done, please do check

Comment: Done, you can check now